# Problemas con acentos Laravel 5 servidor

Tags: php, html, sql-server, laravel-5, utf-8

Tengo esto:

```
<html lang="es">
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

también en `config/database` tengo `'charset' => 'utf8'`.

Aún así tengo problemas con los acentos.

En las pruebas DB local funciona el problema esta al usar la DB del servidor.

Comment: ¿El problema es al insertar o al mostrar los datos? Entiendo que al mostrar los datos. Por otro lado, ¿estás usando php? ¿Has probado a usar `utf8_decode()` antes de mostrar los datos?

Comment: si es al mostrar los datos, utilice utf8_decode y funciono bien, pero quisiera poder evitarme hacer eso en cada campo

Comment: Lo voy a poner como respuesta hasta que pongan una solución mejor. Me alegro de que te haya servido :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías usar `utf8_decode("tu campo con acentos")` para mostrar los valores y que no te salgan símbolos "extraños" con las ñ o los acentos.

Comment: intente usar la instrucción `utf8_decode()` pero a mi no me funciona me pone `?` en el lugar de las tíldes, actualmente estoy usando `Laravel 5.2` y `Sql Server`